# VBA code runs as expected in Debug mode however does not copy updated data when in runtime mode

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle

I require the ability to pass a list of strings into an SQL data connection to verify the set of data exists wholly in the database. Initially tried passing through the set as one parameter in an IN clause in the SQL code however parameters do not work for IN clauses in Excel SQL connections. That led me to pass through each string in the set into a parameter in a LIKE clause in the SQL which does return the data I need. The problem I'm facing is that when I return my table in Excel with the results from the SQL query (with the one parameter passed through), when I go to copy_paste this out to a different table to get the entire list, in debug mode the code runs as expected however in runtime mode the code seems to copy_paste the results from the very first data connection refresh.

I have tried a number of different copy_paste methods, a number of different value assignments and I've tried adding Wait commands but to no avail. Even when I try to use a different approach (count the number of rows in the data connection - where there are no rows or the count function returns an error, tell me that this is a missing record). Even with this approach, it's working in debug mode but just skips over it in runtime.

```vb
Public Sub GetTechLog()
    Dim Comp As Worksheet
    Dim TempDC As Worksheet

    Set Comp = Sheets("Comparison")
    Set TempDC = Sheets("Temp")

    Dim FlyDocData As ListObject
    Dim TRAXData As ListObject
    Dim TempData As ListObject

    Set FlyDocData = Comp.ListObjects("FlyDocs") 'Data to validate exists in TRAX
    Set TRAXData = Comp.ListObjects("TRAX") 'Table to hold CopyPaste data from TRAX
    Set TempData = TempDC.ListObjects("Table_TempFlyDocs") 'Data Connection to the database (TRAX)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To FlyDocData.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        TempDC.Range("A10").Value = FlyDocData.DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value 'This is the parameter passed into the SQL data connection

        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 'Refresh the SQL Data Connection and Table_TempFlyDocs

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")) 'My attempt at adding Wait function to ensure the right data is copy pasted
        TempData.DataBodyRange.Copy 'Copy the newest refresh of the SQL data connection
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
        Comp.Range("C" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats 'Paste this information just into a cell in a different sheet
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm hoping to copy_paste the value of each data connection refresh into a separate table or sheet to have a record of all the information against the list of data in the FlyDocData table.

This is my first post so apologies if there are any glaring omissions of information/misunderstandings. Really hoping someone can help me or suggest some workaround I haven't thought of yet. Frustrating to see your code work in the debugger and not when you try to run it!

Comment: For starters I would set the sheet variables to a sheet *in a specific workbook*. Right now they refer to sheets in the active workbook, which may be another workbook than you intend on using, which often causes differences between running code in debug mode and regularly.

Comment: I can understand why you are doing things this way, but it probably isn't the best.  Have a look at [https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/ado-sql-macros-connecting-database/] as it has some good examples.  (but yes, you need to declare your sheets as `Set Comp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")`